# Filtrar dinámicamente datos en Fullcalendar versión 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy trabajando con la versión 3 del Fullcalendar, hasta ahora me funciona todo, menos cuando quiero filtrar los datos a mostrar según el criterio de flitro aplicado :
Según el valor de un combobox, intento filtrar los datos a mostrar por un campo determinado en el calendario.
Este código me funciona perfecto :

```
events:'php/eventos.php',

  eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) 
  {
      // event.id_tratamiento
      return ['all', event.id_tratamiento].indexOf($('#data_selector').val()) >= 0
  },

  // función combobox filtro :
  $('#data_selector').on('change', function() 
  {
      if (this.value) 
      {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
      }
   }
```

Pero si quiero cambiar dinámicamente el campo a filtrar, no me funciona :

```
    if(condicion==1)
      {
        campo=event.id_tratamiento;
      }
      elseif (condicion==2)
      { 
        campo=event.id_profesional;
      }
      else
      {                           
        campo=event.id_tipo;
      }                    

  eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) 
  {                  
      // event.id_tratamiento
      return ['all', campo].indexOf($('#data_selector').val()) >= 0
          }
```

o

```
  eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) 
  {                  
      // event.id_tratamiento
      return ['all', 'id_'+campo].indexOf($('#data_selector').val()) >= 0
  }
```

No me muestra ningún mensaje de error, y en la pantalla de debug de Chrome tampoco muestra nada anormal, pero no me filtra nada, el calendario se muestra en blanco
Muchas gracias por la ayuda